# Python Indent plugin for Notepad++ not auto indenting

Tags: python, notepad++

I installed Python Indent for Notepad++ for auto indent in Python. But after installing, and then enabling the plugin, there is still no automatic indent. What else do I need to do to make this happen?

Comment: Yes it should auto indent when using `def` or `if` or etc. but it doesnt

Comment: Do you mean installed python? I have python 3 installed and have enabled the plugin. Still doesn't work. And yes the file is a .py file so it is selected for python.

Comment: why are you asking at a programming site and not at a notepad++ site?

Comment: I suggest reporting it as an issue to the Python Indent's author: https://bitbucket.org/Kered13/python-indent-for-notepad/src/default/. I don't know if the plugin's author checks Stack Overflow, but he did mention it over at the Notepad++ forums to contact him via Bitbucket: https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17957/python-indent-plugin-not-working-correctly/14